# Wordpress article and dynamic data/graphs, images to PDF

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, nvd3.js

I'm using Wordpress to manage a newsletter with IssueM, also I need to be able to export the content of a group of articles to PDF (Keep in mind that I'm not a php hardcore developer).I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to generate some data and then creating graphs using NVD3 with javascript.

At this time, all the plugins I found to create PDF's did not work, they only "print" the title of the post(article in IssueM) and nothing else.

I need to be able to export the content, rendered graphs and tables with images, to PDF as they appear in the browser (styled via CSS in my page).

I found there is FPDF, and mPDF, also DOMPDF but they don't specify if they can render the javascript output (which are my NVD3 rendered graphs) to PDF.

Is there any tool that can acomplish this? or,

Do I have to do this by hand? If that's the case, can you tell me an approach?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/printfriendly/

You should be able to add/remove/customize elements that print out:

http://support.printfriendly.com/publisher/developer-questions/include-exclude-content/

It *should* render javascript because it is using javascript (make sure you enable javascript use in the plugin):

http://support.printfriendly.com/publisher/wordpress/javascript-option/

Hope that helps!

Comment: That plugin looks great, but it doesn't seam to be able to export a group of articles to pdf, which is my need, however it is really helpful. Am I missing something or it works only for each post?

Comment: If you can do it manually, get the Nimbus screenshot chrome extension or using Printer Friendly's chrome extension

If you need something automatic / recurring you'll probably need a custom library: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html 

Or, you can give this site a try: http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/